How to enumerate SOAP service endpoints?
I have an ASP .NET Core application with API controllers and several CoreWCF SOAP services inside it.
When someone wants to enumerate "regular" endpoints, it's enough to import EndpointDataSource collection somewhere, e.g. inside controller's ctor:
public MyController(IEnumerable<EndpointDataSource> endpointDataSources)
{
    // ...
}

But this endpoints collection misses information about SOAP services.
Is there any way to enumerate SOAP service endpoints/descriptions?

Maybe it will help somebody.
The only way I found is to register custom IServiceBehavior in DI-container as a singleton. When application starts, CoreWCF applies all registered behaviors to all registered services.
Since IServiceBehavior methods accept ServiceDescription as argument, one can fill list or any other collection like this:
    private readonly object lockObj = new object();
    private readonly List<ServiceDescription> serviceDescriptions = [];

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
        lock (lockObj)
        {
            serviceDescriptions.Add(serviceDescription);
        }
    }

In turn, ServiceDescription contains list of ServiceEndpoints with their ListenUris.
Singleton ensures that there's only one list, and it knows about all services.
